# How to utilize custom form modes to edit a user entity?

Tags: 8, users

My project requires two different pages to edit a user. The first one being at `/settings/{user}/my-profile`, where the user updates their name, address, etc. The other page is at `/settings/{user}/login-credentials`, where the user updates their username, password, etc.

After navigating to `/admin/structure/display-modes/form`, I have created a custom form mode called "My Profile" which has the id `user.my_profile`, and activated it at the bottom of `admin/config/people/accounts/form-display`.

Now I need to create a page that utilizes this new custom form mode, and I'm a bit lost.

I looked into how the standard user edit route is created at `/user/{user}/edit`, and I found the code in the route provider at namespace `Drupal\user\Entity;`. This is what is in that method (other routes have been removed)...

```
public function getRoutes(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $route_collection = new RouteCollection();

  $route = (new Route('/user/{user}/edit'))
    ->setDefaults([
      '_entity_form' => 'user.default',
      '_title_callback' => 'Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::userTitle',
    ])
    ->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE)
    ->setRequirement('user', '\d+')
    ->setRequirement('_entity_access', 'user.update');
  $route_collection->add('entity.user.edit_form', $route);

  return $route_collection;
}
```

Then I did some research on the [routing system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes), and I've created a routing.yml file. The name of my module is `sc`, and the file is at `modules/custom/sc/sc.routing.yml`.

sc.routing.yml

```
sc.my_profile.edit:
  path: '/settings/{user}/my-profile'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.my_profile'
    _title_callback: 'Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::userTitle'
  requirements:
    user: '\d+'
    _entity_access: 'user.update'
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I'm logged in as user1, cleared the cache, and when I navigate to `/settings/1/my-profile`, I get "Page Not Found". Am I on the right track? How do I create these pages with different form modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the form mode in the handlers section of the [user entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.4.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_build().
 */
function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('my_profile', 'Drupal\user\ProfileForm');
}
```

Use the standard class `ProfileForm` as you only want a set new form mode, not a new form class.

Then you can use this new handler in place of `user.default` in the routing file:

```
'_entity_form' => 'user.my_profile',
```

Comment: I've been trying this and it hasn't worked yet for me. How to I edit the routing file? In my `sc.routing.yml` file as listed above, I have the setting `_entity_form: 'user.my_profile',` in the defaults section. When I navigate to `/settings/1/my-profile`, it still shows "Page not found".

Comment: ... and when I navigate to `/user/1/edit`, it is still showing the old original default form mode.

Comment: Is `user.my_profile` really the complete machine name of the form mode, then you get user twice in the route definition, which is not pretty, so I would name the form mode `my_profile` like in my answer. To debug this you can use drupal console to check the route table.

Comment: ... you didn't change the core route or did you?

Comment: No. I'm trying to create two new routes. My project requires two different pages to edit a user. The first one being at '/settings/{user}/my-profile', where the user updates their name, address, etc. The other page is at '/settings/{user}/login-credentials', where the user updates their username, password, etc. I want each route to use a different form mode.

Comment: OK, this shouldn't be a problem when the first is working to register a second one, but why did you ask about the core route `/user/1/edit`, this wouldn't change the form mode if you don't do anything about this?

Comment: Wait a moment, the path of the routing file is wrong `modules/custom/sc/src/Routing/sc.routing.yml` should be in the root folder of the module `modules/custom/sc/sc.routing.yml`

Comment: That was it! I needed both to change the location of the routing.yml file, and set the form class in hook_entity_type_build(). I've got both the routes working now with two separate form modes, (`/my-profile`, and `/login-credentials`). There was also one other error in my original post. I had added a comma at the end of a line in my routing.yml file, and I got an error back. Since it was really the function you gave that was the answer, I've edited the errors out of the original post and marked it as the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to use /settings/my-profile instead of /settings/{user}/my-profile and provide the current user as default value? (should be a question on it's own?)